# Inconsistencies when creating a new Date in Node 8 vs Node 10

Tags: javascript, date

(Yes, these are older releases of Node, I'm in the process of updating an old codebase and am curious as to the reasons for this happening).

If I'm using Node 8 and I run `new Date('1970-01-01 00:00:00')`, I get this date returned to me. If I run `new Date('1972-01-01 00:00:00')`, I get that date returned to me.

However, if I upgrade to Node 10 and run `new Date('1970-01-01 00:00:00')`, I get `1969-12-31T23:00:00.000Z` – an hour is being subtracted from the time, causing it to roll back to the previous year. If I run `new Date('1972-01-01 00:00:00')`, however, I get back `1972-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, without rolling back to the previous year.

It's currently BST here in the UK, which I initially thought could account for the issue, but I'd expect it to happen for *all* created dates, rather than just the year 1970 (and 1971, it turns out).

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a valid ISO date -> `new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")`, otherwise Javascript will see this as locale time.

Comment: @Keith—ECMA-262 is the standard that defines how the built–in parser behaves. '1970-01-01 00:00:00' is a valid ISO 8601 timestamp if parties exchanging it have agreed to replace the "T" with a space ( ).

Comment: @RobG  To be honest, I thought node would parse without the 'T' and parse as ISO, but it doesn't.  And the OP asked specifically about node.  On the other hand, Chrome for example does seem to see this as an ISO Date.  The morale of the story, just stick to a fully qualified ISO String and your good to go.

Comment: @RobG [ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Comment: @Christopher—precisely. ECMA-262 references ISO 8601, but that statement is not normative, hence "*…based upon a simplification of…*". Also, you're referencing ECMA-262 Ed 5.1 which is 10 years old. The latest published version is at [*https://262.ecma-international.org*](https://262.ecma-international.org), but that statement hasn't changed. :-) The point is that there are many ISO 8601 formats, ECMA-262 is the normative reference for ECMAScript and defines support for just one ISO 8601 compliant format.

Answer (score 1):

Node tries to get the local timezone on first usage of Date. Therefor the parsing of dates can vary. See [Difference in assumed time zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#differences_in_assumed_time_zone).

If you want node to assume every date you submit is a UTC-Date, try one of the following:

- use the [iso-date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#using_date.parse) as suggested
- use only the date: `new Date("yyyy-mm-dd")`
- set `process.env.TZ = "UTC";` before accessing any Date() function

Example 1:

```
process.env.TZ = "GMT"; // or GMT+0 or UTC
console.log(Date.parse("1970-01-01")); // 0
console.log(Date.parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00")); // 0
```

Example 2:

```
process.env.TZ = "GMT+1"; // or Europe/London
console.log(Date.parse("1970-01-01")); // 0
console.log(Date.parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00")); // -3600000
```

Example 3:

```
process.env.TZ = "Europe/Berlin"; // or GMT+1
console.log(Date.parse("1970-01-01")); // 0
console.log(Date.parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00")); // -3600000
```